# right to left direction not working properly on urdu font

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have urdu text in html tag (span). Urdu is written right to left, so I applied `direction:rtl`. But it doesn't seem to work because on last line, it leaves space on right. Example will better explain.

```css
.r2l {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span class='r2l'>خدا کرے کے میری عرض پاک پے اترے</span>
  <span class='r2l'>وہ فصل گل جسے </span>
  <span class='r2l'>اندیشہ زوال نہ ہویہاں جو پھول کھلے کھلا رہےصدیوں یہاں 
  سے خزاں کو گزارنے کی مجال نہ ہو</span>
  <span class='r2l'>یہاں جو سبزہ اگے ہمیشہ سبز رہے</span>
  <span class='r2l'>اور ایسا سبز کے جسکیکوئی مثال نہ ہوخدا کرے کے نہ خام 
   ہو سر وقار وطن اور اس کے حسن کو تشوش ماہ وسا ل نہ ہو ہر ایک فرد ہو 
   تہذیب و فن کا</span>
  <span class='r2l'> اوج و کمال کوئی ملول نہ ہو کوئی خستہ حال نہ ہوخدا کرے 
     میرے ایک بھی ہم وطن کے لئےحیات جرم نہ ہو، زندگی وبال نہ ہو</span>
</body>

</html>
```

If you run the snippet and see last line, it doesn't start from right instead it leaves space empty.

**Edit**
Actual scenario added to html, point of having spans is I attach an attribute to each span which is shown on hover (it is time of text added into database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem using `float:right`. This doesn't completely qualifies to what i need, but i worked somehow in my scenario.

```css
.r2l {
  direction: rtl;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span class='r2l'>خدا کرے کے میری عرض پاک پے اترے</span>
  <span class='r2l'>وہ فصل گل جسے </span>
  <span class='r2l'>اندیشہ زوال نہ ہویہاں جو پھول کھلے کھلا رہےصدیوں یہاں 
  سے خزاں کو گزارنے کی مجال نہ ہو</span>
  <span class='r2l'>یہاں جو سبزہ اگے ہمیشہ سبز رہے</span>
  <span class='r2l'>اور ایسا سبز کے جسکیکوئی مثال نہ ہوخدا کرے کے نہ خام 
   ہو سر وقار وطن اور اس کے حسن کو تشوش ماہ وسا ل نہ ہو ہر ایک فرد ہو 
   تہذیب و فن کا</span>
  <span class='r2l'> اوج و کمال کوئی ملول نہ ہو کوئی خستہ حال نہ ہوخدا کرے 
     میرے ایک بھی ہم وطن کے لئےحیات جرم نہ ہو، زندگی وبال نہ ہو</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

rtl doesn't work on `<span>` tags. More information here: [Using <span> to add a direction (dir = "rtl")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473556/using-span-to-add-a-direction-dir-rtl)

Change `<span>` and `</span>` to `<p>` and `</p>`

Comment: so what should be the work around, if i want to use inline element and want direction right to left

Answer (score 1):

`direction` property on itself works on block level elements , `span` is not `block`

use `p` tag instead

```css
.r2l {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p class='r2l'>خدا کرے کے میری عرض پاک پے اترےوہ فصل گل جسے اندیشہ زوال نہ ہویہاں جو پھول کھلے کھلا رہےصدیوں یہاں سے خزاں کو گزارنے کی مجال نہ ہویہاں جو سبزہ اگے ہمیشہ سبز رہےاور ایسا سبز کے جسکیکوئی مثال نہ ہوخدا کرے کے نہ خام ہو سر وقار وطن اور اس کے حسن کو تشوش ماہ وسا ل نہ ہو ہر ایک فرد ہو تہذیب و فن کا اوج و کمال کوئی ملول نہ ہو کوئی خستہ حال نہ ہوخدا کرے میرے ایک بھی ہم وطن کے لئےحیات جرم نہ ہو، زندگی وبال نہ ہو</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the entire site is in Urdu, why not setting the entire site to rtl? Then `<html dir="rtl">` would work just as fine everywhere. One can even apply `dir="rtl"` to `<p>` as well.

Comment: so what should be the work around, if i want to use inline element and want direction right to left, reason is there are multiple span and i want to keep them inline too. Editing question